# How to create a program that will calculate and display the lab and test averages

Tags: python, pycharm

Here are the exact instructions for this program.

Each student in a course needs to submit 3 lab assignments and take 2 tests.  Design a program to do the following.  Ask the user to enter 3 lab scores and 2 test scores.  Calculate and display the lab average and the test average.  Also calculate and display the course grade, which equals 55% of the lab average plus 45% of the test average.

I'm new to python so forgive any syntax errors, etc. I'm stuck figuring out how to calculate and display the course grade.

```
def read_test_scores():
print("ENTER EXAM SCORES: ")
exam = int(input())

print("ENTER ALL LAB SCORES: ")
score1 = int(input())
score2 = int(input())
score3 = int(input())

sum = (score1 + score2 + score3)

tavge = sum / 3.0

return tavge, exam
```

All the help is much appreciated

Comment: When asking about homework (1) **Be aware of your school policy**: asking here for help may constitute cheating. (2) Specify that the question is homework. (3) **Make a good faith attempt** to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question). (4) **Ask about a specific problem** with your existing implementation; see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is guidance on asking homework questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def read_test_scores():
    print("ENTER EXAM SCORES: ")
    exam1 = int(input())
    exam2 = int(input())

    print("ENTER ALL LAB SCORES: ")
    score1 = int(input())
    score2 = int(input())
    score3 = int(input())

    exam_avg = (exam1 + exam2)/2
    lab_avg = (score1 + score2 + score3)/3
    final_score = 0.45 * exam_avg + 0.55 * lab_avg

    print("Exam average is", exam_avg)
    print("Lab average is", lab_avg)
    print("Final score is", final_score)

#Call the function to display results
read_test_scores()
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to keep indentation in python.
I have fixed your code :

```
def read_test_scores():

      exam1,exam2 = input("ENTER EXAM SCORES: ").split(',')

      score1,score2,score3 = input("ENTER ALL LAB SCORES: ").split(',')

      lab = (int(score1) + int(score2) + int(score3))/3

      exam = (int(exam1) + int(exam2))/2

      final = 0.55*lab + 0.45*exam

      print("lab grade {} , exam grade {} , final grade {}".format(lab,exam,final))


read_test_scores()
```

hope it helps. if you have any other question let me know.